# Can only Jedi become force ghosts?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-vader, yoda

A large part of the justification for Darth Vader’s redemption is his appearance as a force ghost. Even though the new movie is not released yet, would it be possible for Palpatine to appear as a force ghost or can only Jedi do this?

Is there any support in the canon books/comics for this? One thing I can think of is Yoda’s reference to Obi Wan’s master in Phantom Menace, but I’m not sure who he is talking about and if it refers to Palpatine’s master or a Jedi?

Comment: If Legends is included, the answer changes over time. Pre-*Phantom Menance*, there are a few cases of non-Jedi becoming Force Ghosts, like in *Tales of the Jedi*. Then Qui-Gon didn't visibly turn into a Force Ghost and it became a rare power, messing everything up.